# how to send value of checkbox using jquery and ajax with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, checkbox

guys how to make a checkbox, if i check it the value on checkbox will send to database without submit form function

this is my checkbox :

```
<input id="active_banner" type='checkbox' name='active_banner' value='1' title='Active Banner' <?=($data->promotion_active == 1)? "checked":""?> />
```

and this is my jquery :

```
<script>
$("#active_banner").click(function() {
    var id = "<?=$data->promotion_banner_id?>"
    var active = $("#active_banner").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ADMIN/ajax/active_banner/",
        data: {id:id,active:active},
    });

    });
</script>
```

i have tried to checked but, there is nothing happen in my ajax controller there is contain :

```
function active_banner(){
    $id = $this->input->get("id",true);
    $active = $this->input->get("active",true);

    $this->Control_panel_m->update_banner_active($id,$active);
    redirect('/ADMIN/'.country_code."/Edit_promotion_banner","refresh");

}
```

guys can you help me how to make it work?

Comment: how do you know nothing happens ? you have no success handler and no error handler and as pointed out the redirect will send back whatever the other controller echos. It will not cause your page to redirect

Comment: Also using `click` will fire if user unchecks the checkbox also but you don't check it's state

Comment: @charlietfl can you help me how to fix this? because when i check i dont see any script running in firebug

Comment: add a console log or alert in the clcik handler callback to see if it even fires. You don't have this code wrapped in document.ready ... if element doesn't exist when it runs it won;t do anything. Then check browser dev tools network to see what happens with actual request

Comment: Also wondering if you have more than one checkbox with same id

Comment: yes i have more than 1 checkbox, that checkbox will input as long as how many data on foreach, i just can only check the first checkbox,  it will work in 1 checkbox but else doesnt work @charlietfl

Comment: ID's must be unique by definition...use class instaed

Comment: huhh i think all off my code are in mess, now i dont know how to do if the checkbox is unchecked, if its uncechk it should be return value 0

Comment: Or add another property so you know whether to turn it on or off at server

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the checked box is selected, click will fire for both check and un checked events

Try using something like following

```
<script>
$("#active_banner").on("change",function(e) {
      var id = "<?=$data->promotion_banner_id?>"
      var active = $(this).is(":checked");
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ADMIN/ajax/active_banner/",
        data: {id:id,active:active},
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: regardless of checking state...OP needs to update server for both conditions

Comment: Updated the code, now in your code the problem is you are sending the value of the check box which will always remain the same for both check/unchecked state.

Comment: right but my point is OP needs to address what to do for both conditions so may need a different property also. Not really clear how this works at server yet though

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$(function(){
$("input[name='active_banner']").click(function() {
    var id = "<?=$data->promotion_banner_id?>"
    var active = $("#active_banner").val();
    if($(this).is("not(:checked)")){
        active = 0;
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ADMIN/ajax/active_banner/",
        data: {id:id,active:active},
        success: function(data){
           window.location = data;//redirect with javascript
        }
    });
    });
  });
```

php:

```
function active_banner(){
    $id = $this->input->get("id",true);
    $active = $this->input->get("active",true);

    $this->Control_panel_m->update_banner_active($id,$active);
    return '/ADMIN/'.$country_code."/Edit_promotion_banner";//return the url to redirect assuming country_code is a variable

}
```

Comment: what about deactivation?

Comment: i haved following your code, but when i have checked there is no any script in firebug, like nothing happen

Comment: does the page redirect?

Comment: its just work on the first checkbox, that checkbox will input as long as how many data on foreach data, i just can only check the first checkbox and will work, but else not

Answer (score 0):

First thing: If you have included your jQuery file as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#active_banner").change(function() {
    var id = "<?=$data->promotion_banner_id?>"
    var active = $("#active_banner").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ADMIN/ajax/active_banner/",
        data: {id:id,active:active},
    });
});
});
</script>
```

In above case, it is necessary to close the `</script>` tag for the include statement. So the jQuery include should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

The version of jQuery could be the same as you have used & it doesn't necessarily need to be what I have mentioned here.

Secondly, since you said you are displaying the checkboxes through a foreach loop, you should put in another attribute on your checkboxes, example: data-id

`<input id="active_banner" type='checkbox' name='active_banner' value='1' title='Active Banner' <?=($data->promotion_active == 1)? "checked":""?> data-id="YOUR_UNIQUE_CHECKBOX_ID" class="active_banner_chk" />`

where YOUR_UNIQUE_CHECKBOX_ID is a unique value which is different for each checkbox.

Then, modify your jQuery to be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".active_banner_chk").click(function() {
    var id = "<?=$data->promotion_banner_id?>";
    var active = 0;

    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        var active = $(this).attr('data-id');
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ADMIN/ajax/active_banner/",
        data: {id:id,active:active},
    });
});
});
</script>
```

You can also avoid adding the extra attribute of data-id & instead have your jQuery & HTML element like below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".active_banner_chk").click(function() {
    var id = "<?=$data->promotion_banner_id?>";
    var active = 0;

    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        var active = $(this).val();
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ADMIN/ajax/active_banner/",
        data: {id:id,active:active},
    });
});
});
</script>
<input id="active_banner" type='checkbox' name='active_banner' value='1' title='Active Banner' <?=($data->promotion_active == 1)? "checked":""?> class="active_banner_chk" />
```

Calling your jQuery based on the class name & then using `$this.val()` instead of the `$('#active_banner').val()` ensures that you get the value of the current checkbox instead of the first checkbox always.

Comment: why u put `var active=0`? i need to send it become 1 as long as i have include in the input value

Comment: Incase the checkbox is not checked, then it will send the value of 'active' as 0. If it's checked, then it will send the input value of that checkbox.